# SharePoint Library form does not Submit Data

Tags: sharepoint-designer

SharePoint Library form does not Submit Data once I create a custom workflow.
The uploaded Document is saved and the workflow begins but the form does not submit the meta data or does it close. Once I remove the workflow the form functions.

Comment: welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much (any) information but I'll take a wild guess: You're getting a version conflict when your form is posting because your workflow is also making changes to the document's list item.

Change your workflow to run on ItemUpdated instead of ItemCreated, so it'll wait for the form submission to complete.

Comment: Yes your guess is correct, I was considering the version conflict, and had the workflow wait for 5min...but that didn't work . I'll try your suggestion. Thanks